# How do I remove the space to the left of these chords?

Tags: horizontal-alignment

I'm using the gchords package and want either zero margin (the chord goes in an image) or the assurance that the margin is a set number of pixels I can trim.

```
\documentclass[preview]{standalone}
\usepackage{gchords}
\begin{document}
\hsize=0mm
\begin{verse}
\smallchords
\chord{}{n,n,p1,p1,p1,n}{}
\end{verse}
\end{document}
```

I'm not sure this matters but here's an example of the conversion to image:

```
dvipng -D 450 -o gchtest.png gchtest.dvi
```

Any help much appreciated!

Comment: Maybe you're interested in http://ctan.org/pkg/guitarchordschemes

Answer (score 1):

There are at least three problems of which I can solve at most two.

The first problem is that `verse` is a list. Hence, its contents are going to be indented, as is usual for lists. This can be solved by not using it. `standalone` likes an environment, but we can create a wrapper environment which does nothing make make a group, to keep it happy.

That one was easy.

The second problem is that `gchords.sty` is very badly written in at least some ways. Of particular interest here is the fact that it introduces enormous amounts of white space of all kinds. It randomly comments line endings which wouldn't introduce a space anyway and then goes and includes blank lines, uncommented line endings, commented line endings preceded by spaces and so on.

This should be addressed in the package by the package's maintainer. By way of illustration, I've modified `\smallchords` and \chord` to remove most of the spurious spaces. I haven't removed unnecessary comment signs, of which there are also many, because these do no actual harm.

This is easy to fix in theory, but somebody has to go through the package and do the work and the maintainer has to accept the changes (or make them) and push the result to CTAN. Alternatively, you can fork the package by copying it to a new name, changing the banner and fixing the code yourself.

Third, the left-most string is halfway between `0` and `1`, I think, but I'm not sure how to adjust it by `-0.5` as opposed to `1` or `-1`.

Also, I'm not sure if this is required or if this is really part of the diagram itself.

In the code below, I set `\xoff` and `\yoff` to `0` for illustration purposes. Again, it maybe these should be `2`. Setting them to `0` should put the lower left corner of the diagram at `0,0`, which suggests that the `0.5` offset is supposed to be part of the diagram. I don't know what a diagram like this should look like, so can't tell.

Here's the result:

[image: result]

```
\documentclass[]{standalone}
\usepackage{gchords}
\newenvironment{mychords}{}{}
\standaloneenv{mychords}
\makeatletter
\renewcommand\chord[3]{%
  \vbox{%
    \hbox{%
      \ascale=\chordsize
      \truewidth=\strings\advance\truewidth by -1%
      \advance\truewidth by \xoff
      \topline=\numfrets
      \advance\topline by \yoff
      \advance\topline by 2%
%
%       %%% The Diagram itself %%%%%%%%%
      \unitlength\ascale
      \begin{picture}(\truewidth,\topline)%
        \advance\topline by -1%
        \advance\truewidth by -\xoff
        \myvpos=\yoff\advance\myvpos by \numfrets
        %%% Parse the modifier string %%
        \newcommand\topbar{n}%
        \@tfor\modstr:=#1\do
        {%
          \def\ttest{t}%
          \ifx\modstr\ttest{\linethickness{\topfretsiz}\put(\xoff,\myvpos){\chline{\truewidth}}\thinlines}%
          \else
          {%
            \advance\topline by -1%
            \put(\xoff,\topline){%
              \hbox to 0pt{\hss\fretposfont\modstr~}%
            }%
          }%
          \fi%
        }%
%
%         %%% Horizontal lines (frets)%%%%
        \mylength=0%
        \myvpos=\yoff
        \advance\myvpos by 1%  % first fret starts a bit higher
        \@whilenum \mylength<\numfrets \do {%
          \put(\xoff,\myvpos){%
            \chline{\truewidth}%
          }%
          \advance\mylength by 1%
          \advance\myvpos   by 1}%
%
%         %%% The Dots %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
        \newcommand\fnow{n}%
        \newcommand\pnow{n}%
        \newcommand\snow{n}%
        \newcommand\Lnow{n}%
%
        \edef\notelabel{}%
%
        \putdots{#2}{\chordsize}%
        \put(\xoff,0){\hbox to \truewidth\ascale{\hss\namefont #3\hss}}%
      \end{picture}%
    }%
  }%
}
\renewcommand\smallchords{%
  \def\chordsize{2.0mm}%    % distance between two frets (and two strings)
  \font\fingerfont=cmr5%    % font used for numbering fingers
  \font\namefont=cmr10%     % font used for labeling of the chord
  \font\fretposfont=cmr7%   % font used for the fret position marker
  \def\dampsymbol{$\scriptstyle\times$}%    % symbol of the `damp this string' marker
  \def\opensymbol{$\scriptstyle\circ$}%     % symbol of the `open string' marker
}
\renewcommand\xoff{0}
\renewcommand\yoff{0}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
\begin{mychords}
  \smallchords
  \chord{}{n,n,p1,p1,p1,n}{}%
\end{mychords}
\end{document}
```

Note that the package file should not be using `\makeatletter` and `\makeatother`. `@` is already a letter when a package file is read.

I tried removing spaces in `\putdots`. However, this made no difference to the result.